# Mouseover e Mouseout com animate.css em uso (wobble)

Tags: javascript, css, animate.css

Não consigo fazer o wobble do Animate.css funcionar logo que a minha pagina web carrega, pois estou tentando fazer efeito de mouseover / mouseout e nao esta funcionando. 
O objeto começa com o wobble acionado, ao fazer o mouseover, este para de fazer o animate wobble. Quando fizer mouseout, a mesma classe (wobble) deverá voltar a funcionar, porém náo consigo fazer rodar. Onde estou errando ?

```
<div class="cabeceira">
   <img src="logo.jpg">
</div> 
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
         $("menu").on('mouseover', function(){
         $(this).removeClass('animated wobble');
      });

      $("menu").on('mouseout', function(){
         $(this).addClass('animated wobble');
      });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara tinha algumas coisas estranhas no seu Script, primeiro que vc está usando como referencia o elemento `$("menu")` sendo que ele não existe nesse HTML que vc postou, depois que vc não declarou se ele é uma classe, usando o "." ou se é um ID usando o "#", então sendo classe ficaria assim por exemplo: `$(".menu")`

Se eu entendi vc quer fazer o wobble ao colocar e retirar o mouse do elemento correto? Se for isso o exemplo abaixo deve resolver. OBS: Coloquei um pequeno CSS apenas para ficar melhor a exibição no Snippet do Stackoverflow

**Dica:** Se vc quiser que fique balançando `infinitamente` e só para quando o mouse estiver em cima basta colocar a classe `infinite` na tag, dessa forma: `<div class="menu animated wobble infinite">`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".menu").on('mouseover', function(){
     $(this).removeClass('animated wobble');
  });

  $(".menu").on('mouseout', function(){
     $(this).addClass('animated wobble');
  });
});
```

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<div class="menu animated wobble">
    <img src="http://placecage.com/100/100">
</div>
```

Comment: comi bola mesmo na classe ... nao referenciei o menu na div e por isso ficou estranho ... A ideia era exatamente a que vc fez mesmo, deixar o wobble ativo e ao passar o mouse, ele parar com o movimento ... e ao retirar o mouse, voltar o movimento, perfeito ! A dica do infinite dentro da classe achei o máximo ! Liçao aprendida!
Agora estou vendo como fazer isso com o botao em checked, pois é a condição real ao qual tenho aqui, pois tenho um botao que aciona o menu e ele tem a posição checked, como por exemplo, 
.menu:checked {
    codigo css;
}
mas já ajudou muito!

Comment: @EitaEhNOiz entendi a sua intenção. Bom, tenta colocar esse código ai na situação real e olha os ajustes finos que vc vai precisar fazer. Se vc precisar de mais uma força me fala. Só lembre que o `:checked` precisa ser clicado, ele até pode ter um mouseOver, mas para pegar o estilo do estado `:checked` vc vai precisar clicar nele de qq forma...

Comment: vou pensar em uma forma aqui com este :checked, talvez um script dentro dele, com o wobble pausado, e ao sair, este wobble volte ao estado normal.
Talvez assim, .menu-open:checked {
      -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.935, 0, 0.34, 1.33);
      transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.935, 0, 0.34, 1.33);
    }

$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".menu-open").on('mouseover', function(){
     $(this).removeClass('animated wobble');
  });

  $(".menu-open").on('mouseout', function(){
     $(this).addClass('animated wobble');
  });
});

Comment: @EitaEhNOiz eu entendo muito pouco de jQuery, mas se vc tiver uma dúvida mais complicada abre uma nova pergunta que tem gente aqui que consegue te responder de boa. Sobre o :checked para ele funcionar vc vai precisar de um input:checkbox, ou então usar o prórpio jQuery para comocar uma classe "active" nessa div quando vc clicar nela. Boa sorte ai, tamo junto!